# How to write if/else in ionic html page?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I made an Ionic WordPress app that gives me an error every time a post is published without a featured photo.
What I'm trying to do is *filter out* those posts that *doesn't* have a photo but I don't know how to use *if/else* condition in Ionic.
This is the code for **home.html**

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
    <img src="{{item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url}}"/>
    <ion-card-content>
    ...
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to remove items from `items` that don't have a thumbnail, it's better to do it on the backend when you get them.

```
this.items = this.items.filter(function(item) {
  return (item && 
          item._embedded &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0] &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail &&
          item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url);
});
```

If you want to get every item, thumbnail or no, but hide the thumbnail if it doesn't exist, use `*ngIf` on your `img` tag.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let item of items">
  <img *ngIf="item && 
              item._embedded &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'] &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0] &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail &&
              item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url"
       src="{{item._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url}}"/>
</ion-card>
```

*Note: The reason you should check each layer of the object is because if any one of them is missing, you'll get a TypeError saying "could not find property X of undefined".*